# Windows PC, Ubuntu installation: wubi vs native vs virtualized

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtualization

My PC is running Windows 7, I need to install Ubuntu for some development (Python / django / etc). Considering the need of running quite memory-consuming apps (like Aptana and/or other Eclipse based IDEs) what are pros & cons of each of following choices:

- native (parallel) installation
- wubi
- virtualization (Windows 7 + VirtualBOX hosting Ubuntu guest)

I'm just used to developing under Ubuntu, but now I have the new machine which need to run Windows 7 (VisualStudio) and wondering which is the best choice.

What is the real penalty of running under VirtualBox? The adventage is no rebooting and saving the session...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, a native install will have the best performance. With virtualization you can get good performance, too.

For the virtualization case, check this question on Unix & Linux: [Any reason NOT to run Linux in a VM all the time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38379/15630). If your hardware is sufficiently powerful (a good amount of RAM, mostly), there should be no problem.

As for Wubi, the Wubi install might have a small performance hit if the partition is fragmented (Wubi installs to a "disk image"), also it might get damaged if the Windows partition gets corrupted.

Comment: 12GB of RAM but most likely extending to 16. Is that a "good amount" for virtualizing Ubuntu + heavy Eclipse IDE?

Comment: @michal Yes, with this you can easily give 2 or 4 GB RAM to the VM which should be more than enough.

Comment: thanks, but still I'm wondering what is the penalty of virtualization.
can I check it somehow, like benchmarking the CPU with the same tool under (native) Windows and (virtualized) Ubuntu?